# SQL Server - Union

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, union

```
    SELECT CMS_ORGANIZATION.ORG_ACTOR_GUID, CMS_EMPLOYMENT.PERIOD_TO AS EventDate, CMS_INDIVIDUAL.FULL_NAME as Name, 'Ceased' AS EventType, 'Overseeing Executive Director' AS TypeOfChange, CMS_ORGANIZATION.REG_NAME
    FROM CMS_EMPLOYMENT INNER JOIN CMS_INDIVIDUAL ON CMS_EMPLOYMENT.EMPLOYEE_ACTOR_GUID = CMS_INDIVIDUAL.IND_ACTOR_GUID INNER JOIN
         CMS_ROLE_ASSUMED ON CMS_EMPLOYMENT.ROLE_ASSUMED_GUID = CMS_ROLE_ASSUMED.ROLE_ASSUMED_PK INNER JOIN CMS_ORGANIZATION ON CMS_ROLE_ASSUMED.TARGET_ACTOR_GUID = CMS_ORGANIZATION.ORG_ACTOR_GUID INNER JOIN
         CMS_MASTER_SETUP ON CMS_EMPLOYMENT.DESIGNATION_GUID = CMS_MASTER_SETUP.MASTER_SETUP_PK    
    UNION

    SELECT CMS_ORGANIZATION.ORG_ACTOR_GUID, CMS_ORG_SHARES_HISTORY.EFFECTIVE_DATE AS EventDate, CMS_MASTER_SETUP.Description as Currency, CONVERT(varchar(50), CAST(CMS_ORG_SHARES.AUTHORIZED_CAP_AMOUNT AS money), 1), 
           'Changed to ' AS EventType, 'Share Capital (Authorized)' AS TypeOfChange, CMS_ORGANIZATION.REG_NAME
    FROM   CMS_ORGANIZATION INNER JOIN CMS_ORG_SHARES ON CMS_ORGANIZATION.ORG_ACTOR_GUID = CMS_ORG_SHARES.ORG_ACTOR_GUID INNER JOIN CMS_ORG_SHARES_HISTORY ON CMS_ORG_SHARES.ORG_SHARES_PK = CMS_ORG_SHARES_HISTORY.ORG_SHARES_GUID INNER JOIN CMS_MASTER_SETUP  ON CMS_ORGANIZATION.CURRENCY_GUID = CMS_MASTER_SETUP.MASTER_SETUP_PK 
    UNION

    SELECT CMS_ORGANIZATION.ORG_ACTOR_GUID, CMS_ORG_SHARES_HISTORY.EFFECTIVE_DATE AS EventDate, CONVERT(varchar(50), CAST(CMS_ORG_SHARES.PAID_UP_CAP_AMOUNT AS money), 1), 
           'Changed to' AS EventType, 'Share Capital (Paid Up)' AS TypeOfChange, CMS_ORGANIZATION.REG_NAME
    FROM   CMS_ORGANIZATION INNER JOIN CMS_ORG_SHARES ON CMS_ORGANIZATION.ORG_ACTOR_GUID = CMS_ORG_SHARES.ORG_ACTOR_GUID INNER JOIN
           CMS_ORG_SHARES_HISTORY ON CMS_ORG_SHARES.ORG_SHARES_PK = CMS_ORG_SHARES_HISTORY.ORG_SHARES_GUID
```

I have gotten this error:
"All queries combined using a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator must have an equal number of expressions in their target lists." on the first line. May I ask how isit possible to query "CMS_MASTER_SETUP.Description as Currency, CONVERT(varchar(50), CAST(CMS_ORG_SHARES.AUTHORIZED_CAP_AMOUNT AS money), 1)" under the Name Column but both as Currency

Answer (score 0):

Since you must have the same number of columns in each union group, you could include a blank placeholder in the first and third group: e.g.
SELECT 
..
'' as Currency,
..

if that accomplishes goal. That would give you 7 columns in each group.

Comment: It occurs to me now, too, that you could do a simple + Character. 

CMS_MASTER_SETUP.Description + ', ' +  CONVERT(varchar(50), CAST(CMS_ORG_SHARES.AUTHORIZED_CAP_AMOUNT AS money), 1) as Currency

Comment: that would not possible to include blank placeholder as the data from the first query differs from the second one. For instance, first query has no currency value (NULL). I maybe required to run another query which allows me to set the currency for instance if the currency in second query is not inserted, automatically to "USD" later on. But if i do that, the first and third query will have the currency "USD" if you know what I mean

Answer (score 0):

The error clearly says that "operator must have an equal number of expressions in their target lists". Which means you should have same set of fields in the SELECT clause across all the 3 queries.

Example: You are selecting "CMS_INDIVIDUAL.FULL_NAME as Name" in the first query, but you are not having a Name field in the other two queries. You will not be able to do UNION like this.

Comment: that would not possible to include blank placeholder as the data from the first query differs from the second one. For instance, first query has no currency value (NULL). I maybe required to run another query which allows me to set the currency for instance if the currency in second query is not inserted, automatically to "USD" later on. But if i do that, the first and third query will have the currency "USD" if you know what I mean

Comment: I am not sure if you understand how UNION works. Unless you have same set of fields fetched, UNION cannot be used. I am still not sure why you are selecting Name field in the first query and not in other 2. At least you can 'NULL as Name' in the other 2 queries. You can do a similar thing for other fields that are not matching across the queries